# How to get custom favorites icons in Safari 8 on Yosemite?

Tags: safari, macos

I am wanting to add custom favorites icons (i.e. new tab page) for my website in Safari 8 on Yosemite. I have tried the open graph tag `og:image` with both png and jpg formats. I have also looked over the source of several sites that had the custom icons in my favorites page, including a site that appeared to update its icon, and I still cannot find the right way to include these icons. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You speak about favicon ?

Comment: No. I am referring to the favorites icons in the new tab page in Safari.

Comment: You have tried to delete the associated file in /Users/USER_NAME/Library/Safari/LocalStorage/http.yourwebsite.localstorage before adding your website in Favourite ?

Comment: Yes. Nothing happens. The custom icon has never showed. Only default icon has shown, making me believe that I am not implementing the use of the icon properly.

Comment: I think that's a stack overflow question :/

Comment: @MrMojoRisin It does not. How is this a software-development question?

Comment: @Rob Mmm sorry I just saw "my website" so I was thinking about development. Because the icons website generally depends of the website code...

Comment: @MrMojoRisin It's for the user personal Safari layout. This is definately the right place here. And now I seriously wonder how to do this..

Comment: @Rob ohh my bad, now I wonder how to do this too o.O

Comment: @Rob, me too, hence the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not related to OS X, so I’ll let the moderator move this question to other network. But I’m still going to answer this. The one you’re talking about is Apple Touch Icon which can be implemented by using the markup below:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
```

There are multiple sizes because it needs to support Retina and non-Retina display.

Source: [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/favicon-quiz/)

Comment: Not working. I added these at the 57, 120, and 152 sizes (as per the apple website) and the favorites are not responding.

Comment: What is your website?

Comment: http://pintsizedtreasures.com

Comment: I opened your site and didn’t find the mentioned touch icons. Have you inserted it?

Comment: I did insert them, but the icons did not show, so I removed them. Now, however, the favorite icons are now showing in Safari. I have no idea why. Go figure.

Comment: Keep them available. Your bookmarks icon will use these in Safari 8 and iOS home screen icon.

Comment: I put one of them back. After doing research I saw some recommended just using one icon (since it will be called anyhow and it is only a slightly larger than the smaller ones).

Answer (score 0):

Safari (at least version 9.0.2 on Yosemite) does not show favicon in the tabs. For *a client side solution* i recommend [SafariStand](http://hetima.com/safaristand/). It is a SIMBL plug-in that adds many extra features to the Safari such as **favicon on tabs** and bookmark bar, separate download and bookmark panel, and other tweaks.